# Laravel centos vs ubuntu performance

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, centos

Laravel on Centos 7.5 with PHP 7.2 has a terrible response time of 500-600ms on each page refresh. At first, my first thought was that my code is bad so then I tested a clean install of Laravel, but it was the same 500ms.

After that, I tested Laravel on ubuntu 18.04 and to my surprise, in debug, mode response time was below 20ms! I did a diff of my php.ini file centos/ubuntu but the config was pretty much the same. Tests were performed on a 5$ DigitalOcean droplet.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Same PHP version on both OS's?